# Incorrect Joda Time parsing of String to LocalDate

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Here's the string I'm trying to format

```
10-12-2015
```

Which stands for october 12 2015. However when I'm parsing it as a a LocalDate. using this

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(dto.getTargetDate(), DateTimeFormat.forPattern("mm-dd-yyyy"))
```

the result is always `2015-01-12`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* You're not reading the [JavaDoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `mm` to `MM`, because `mm` is for minutes.

Thus, when parsing you put a year equal to 2015, day to 12 and minutes to 10. All other fields are default values, month is January, hours - 00, and so on. That's why you get 12 January 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Month is uppercase `M`. The lowercase `m` is *minute*.